# how to bulk update in Hibernate using HQL

Tags: hibernate, sql-update, hql

I am having a list of elements which needs to be updated and i use the following code.

I am new to hibernate and with the errors i am not sure where I did the mistake.

Thanks for reading

```
    int result = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("update <table_name> TN "
            + "SET TN.COLUM_2= :column2, TN.COLUM_3= :column3,
            + "Where TN.COLUM_10 IN(:column10")")               
            .setLong("column2", column2)
            .setString("column3", column3)
            .setParameterList("column10", column10)

            .executeUpdate();
```

I get exception.

```
"<table_name> is not mapped"
```

Any reference or help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: <table_name> should be the name of hibernate entity and not the table name, I guess that's where the issues is.

Comment: ao use `Session.createSQLQuery()` instead of `createQuery()`